# How to use ngFor to display the data as matrix

Tags: angular

- Edited to put more description *

I am new on Angular2. I have use "ngFor" to iterate over array of objects and show them as matrix having 3 columns for each row. For example;

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
...
</div>
<div class="row">
...
</div>
```

Could anyone help me on this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

With `*ngFor` you can iterate over an array. If the array items are arrays, you can nest `*ngFor` like:

```
@Component({
  selector: '...'
  template: `
<div class="row" *ngFor="let row of matrix">
  <div class="col" *ngFor="let col of row">
   <div class="card">{{col}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
`
})
class Component {
  matrix = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f'],['g', 'h', 'i']];
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. it is array of objects; not array of array of objects. how to iterate over it to show 3 columns(3 objects) for each row?

Comment: That's what Thierry's answer explains, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If your data are contained within an array of objects. You could use a custom pipe to iterate over object keys:

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    if (!value) {
      return value;
    }

    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

Here is the way to use it:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let obj of data">
  <div class="col" *ngFor="let keyValues of obj | keys>
    <div class="card">{{keyValues.key}} = {{keyValues.key}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The structure of data used are the following:

```
this.data = [
  { prop1: 'val1 a', prop2: 'val2 a', ... }
  { prop1: 'val1 b', prop2: 'val2 b', ... }
  { prop1: 'val1 c', prop2: 'val2 c', ... }
  (...)
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is old but i found a way to do a maxtric on data from a single array.

my data structure

```
data = [
    {
          from: 'AB',
          to : 'AB',
          value: true
     }
    {
          from: 'AB',
          to : 'CD',
          value: false
     }
    {
          from: 'CD',
          to : 'AB',
          value: true
     }
    {
          from: 'CD',
          to : 'CD',
          value: false
     }
]
```

**Step 1**

You need to define what your columns and line head will be.
In this case i had the same values of lines and columns.

```
subsctractHeads(array) {
    cols = [ ...new Set(array.map(item => item.from)) ]
}
```

This will give an array `cols = ['AB','CD']`

**Step 2**

Display you data in a table like matrix

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th *ngFor="let column of cols" > {{ column }} </th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of cols" >
         <th> {{ row }} </th>
         <ng-container *ngFor="let dest of cols" >
               <ng-container *ngFor="cell to of data" >
                    <td *ngIf="cell.from === row && cell.to === dest" ></td>
                         {{ cell.value }}
                </ng-container>
         </ng-container>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Should display a simple matrix