# How to load custom components dynamically to div? Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-forms

**ANGULAR2**,
I want to load all my custom component into a html div based on customComponentsList.

My actual scenario is considor i have

```
A(0-row,0-column),B(0,1),C(0,2),D(1,0),E(1,1),F(2,0), G(2,1), H(2-row,2-column))
```

custom components.

I have to display in div as per row and column positions like

```
    A B C
    D E
    F G H
```

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Angular 2? Sounds rather like pure CSS issues.

Comment: thank you @GünterZöchbauer, really helpful and i have one doubt ,how can i load components with row,column positioin in dom

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak, i think u didn't get my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work

```
<div #target x="0" y="0"></div>
<div #target x="1" y="0"></div>
<div #target x="2" y="0"></div>

<div #target x="0" y="1"></div>
<div #target x="1" y="1"></div>
<div #target x="2" y="1"></div>

<div #target x="0" y="2"></div>
<div #target x="1" y="2"></div>
<div #target x="2" y="2"></div>
```

```
@ViewChildren('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) targets: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

// this.targets is not filled before `ngAfterViewInit()` was called
addComponent(x, y) {
  let t = this.targets(y * 3 + x); 
}
```

Comment: I did it using your answer 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656742/how-to-use-ngfor-to-display-the-data-as-matrix'.

Comment: <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of tabs">
      <td *ngFor="let col of row">
        <dcl-wrapper [type]="col"></dcl-wrapper>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>